# Which bitcoin documentation is the official one for bitcoin core?

Tags: documentation

English Google searches about `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-cli` often lead to two sites:

- https://en.bitcoin.it
- https://bitcoin.org

Any idea which one is the official one, endorsed by the maintainers?

Comment: The material on bitcoin.org doesn't seem to document Bitcoin Core (which is a specific software wallet), but rather the Bitcoin protocol in general.  The only material specific to Bitcoin Core is linked out to the bitcoin.it wiki.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a single documentation endorsed by the maintainers.  My guess is that it would depend on which maintainer you ask.  Perhaps your question is more like this one:  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46067/can-we-unravel-bitcoin-core/46068

Comment: The word "official" doesn't exist in decentralized free software like Bitcoin. Both links you mention are good sites. Make sure to stay away from bitcoin.com though. It's full of lies and scams.

Comment: @Jannes Clearly, there is no *official* documentation in a decentralized system, the same way there is no *official* bitcoin implementation. However, there is often a widely accepted, well maintained and maintainer-endorsed source of information for such projects.

Comment: @AdamMatan Correct. That's why I said both your links are good. https://bitcoincore.org is another good one with human readable summaries and FAQs of technical stuff.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no official documentation.

The closest you can get to it is the combination of the GitHub:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

With the whitepaper:
https://bitcoincore.org/bitcoin.pdf

Changelog appears with every version on the core site, e.g.:
https://bitcoincore.org/en/releases/0.12.1/

And lastly, while I already linked to GitHub it is probably worth mentioning that open and closed issues are documented there:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=

Hope this helps.